# Loopback.io 401 on remote method?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I've defined a remote method named `retrieve`

and the following roles `admin`, `barkeeper`.

The model acl is

```
"acls": [
{
  "accessType": "*",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "DENY"
},
{
  "accessType": "*",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "admin",
  "permission": "ALLOW"
},
{
  "accessType": "EXECUTE",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "barkeeper",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "retrieve"
}
],
```

The problem is that when I'm logged in either as an `admin` user or a `barkeeper` user and call `/retrieve` I get 401

Any ideas?

Edit:

Loopback logs show:

```
loopback:security:access-context ---AccessContext---
loopback:security:access-context principals:
loopback:security:access-context principal: {"type":"USER","id":"583adfd78753a610006c586b"}
loopback:security:access-context modelName Order
loopback:security:access-context modelId undefined
loopback:security:access-context property retrieve
loopback:security:access-context method retrieve
loopback:security:access-context accessType READ
loopback:security:access-context accessToken:
loopback:security:access-context   id "wm54iPCZuOYWBYujAHFKloo4GWHq3ceDvDaRui1YjOlDLxeQWznQ3cRdolWHu0sc"
loopback:security:access-context   ttl 1209600
loopback:security:access-context getUserId() 583adfd78753a610006c586b
loopback:security:access-context isAuthenticated() true
loopback:security:role Custom resolver found for role $everyone
loopback:security:role isInRole(): admin
loopback:security:access-context ---AccessContext---
loopback:security:access-context principals:
loopback:security:access-context principal: {"type":"USER","id":"583adfd78753a610006c586b"}
loopback:security:access-context modelName Order
loopback:security:access-context modelId undefined
loopback:security:access-context property retrieve
loopback:security:access-context method retrieve
loopback:security:access-context accessType READ
loopback:security:access-context accessToken:
loopback:security:access-context   id "wm54iPCZuOYWBYujAHFKloo4GWHq3ceDvDaRui1YjOlDLxeQWznQ3cRdolWHu0sc"
loopback:security:access-context   ttl 1209600
loopback:security:access-context getUserId() 583adfd78753a610006c586b
loopback:security:access-context isAuthenticated() true
loopback:security:role isInRole(): admin
loopback:security:access-context ---AccessContext---
loopback:security:access-context principals:
loopback:security:access-context principal: {"type":"USER","id":"583adfd78753a610006c586b"}
loopback:security:access-context modelName Order
loopback:security:access-context modelId undefined
loopback:security:access-context property retrieve
loopback:security:access-context method retrieve
loopback:security:access-context accessType READ
loopback:security:access-context accessToken:
loopback:security:access-context   id "wm54iPCZuOYWBYujAHFKloo4GWHq3ceDvDaRui1YjOlDLxeQWznQ3cRdolWHu0sc"
loopback:security:access-context   ttl 1209600
loopback:security:access-context getUserId() 583adfd78753a610006c586b
loopback:security:access-context isAuthenticated() true
loopback:security:role isInRole(): barkeeper
loopback:security:access-context ---AccessContext---
loopback:security:access-context principals:
loopback:security:access-context principal: {"type":"USER","id":"583adfd78753a610006c586b"}
loopback:security:access-context modelName Order
loopback:security:access-context modelId undefined
loopback:security:access-context property retrieve
loopback:security:access-context method retrieve
loopback:security:access-context accessType READ
loopback:security:access-context accessToken:
loopback:security:access-context   id "wm54iPCZuOYWBYujAHFKloo4GWHq3ceDvDaRui1YjOlDLxeQWznQ3cRdolWHu0sc"
loopback:security:access-context   ttl 1209600
loopback:security:access-context getUserId() 583adfd78753a610006c586b
loopback:security:access-context isAuthenticated() true
loopback:security:role Role found: {"id":"583adfd78753a610006c586a","name":"admin","created":"2016-11-27T13:29:58.664Z","modified":"2016-11-27T13:29:58.664Z"}
loopback:security:role Role found: {"id":"583adfd78753a610006c586a","name":"admin","created":"2016-11-27T13:29:58.664Z","modified":"2016-11-27T13:29:58.664Z"}
loopback:security:role Role found: {"id":"583adfd78753a610006c586d","name":"barkeeper","created":"2016-11-27T13:29:58.665Z","modified":"2016-11-27T13:29:58.665Z"}
loopback:security:role Role mapping found: null
loopback:security:role isInRole() returns: null
loopback:security:role Role mapping found: null
loopback:security:role isInRole() returns: null
loopback:security:role Role mapping found: null
loopback:security:role isInRole() returns: null
loopback:security:acl The following ACLs were searched: 
loopback:security:acl ---ACL---
loopback:security:acl model Order
loopback:security:acl property *
loopback:security:acl principalType ROLE
loopback:security:acl principalId $everyone
loopback:security:acl accessType *
loopback:security:acl permission DENY
loopback:security:acl with score: 7495
loopback:security:acl ---Resolved---
loopback:security:access-context ---AccessRequest---
loopback:security:access-context  model Order
loopback:security:access-context  property retrieve
loopback:security:access-context  accessType READ
loopback:security:access-context  permission DENY
loopback:security:access-context  isWildcard() false
loopback:security:access-context  isAllowed() false
Unhandled error for request GET /Orders/retrieve?access_token=wm54iPCZuOYWBYujAHFKloo4GWHq3ceDvDaRui1YjOlDLxeQWznQ3cRdolWHu0sc: Error: Authorization Required
```

Why is it resolving with that ACL if the user has admin role?

Comment: Could you run `set DEBUG=loopback:security:acl  && node . ` (windows) or `DEBUG=loopback:security:acl node . ` (Unix), then make an authenticated requests and show the output of the console ?

Comment: Basically the idea is to use [debug strings](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Setting-debug-strings.html) for figuring out what is going on.

Comment: @Overdrivr just updated the question

Comment: Ah sorry I meant to use a broader debug string -> `set DEBUG=loopback:security:* && node . ` This one will display all logs under the security category

Comment: @Overdrivr just added new logs

Answer (score 0):

Where are you creating your admin and barkeeper roles and the RoleMappings for your users and their roles?

I.e., [In the documentation example](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Defining-and-using-roles.html) Users are created as a one-time operation, and then later the Role *and* RoleMappings are created.

In your logs you can see that there doesn't seem to be any RoleMapping for your user (the arrows), even though the Role is clearly there:

```
loopback:security:role Role found: {"id":"583adfd78753a610006c586a","name":"admin","created":"2016-11-27T13:29:58.664Z","modified":"2016-11-27T13:29:58.664Z"}
loopback:security:role Role found: {"id":"583adfd78753a610006c586a","name":"admin","created":"2016-11-27T13:29:58.664Z","modified":"2016-11-27T13:29:58.664Z"}
loopback:security:role Role found: {"id":"583adfd78753a610006c586d","name":"barkeeper","created":"2016-11-27T13:29:58.665Z","modified":"2016-11-27T13:29:58.665Z"}
loopback:security:role Role mapping found: null   <------- 
loopback:security:role isInRole() returns: null   <------- 
loopback:security:role Role mapping found: null   <------- 
loopback:security:role isInRole() returns: null   <------- 
loopback:security:role Role mapping found: null   <------- 
loopback:security:role isInRole() returns: null   <-------
```

Maybe there's an error with the code that assigns those RoleMappings to the Users.